# Creating a dictionary from text file with "\" separator

Tags: python, dictionary

I read in a .txt file and generated a list from it with this code:

```
infilename = 'aa_data.txt'
infile = open(infilename,'r')
aa = infile.readlines()
aa_info = []
for string in aa:
    if string[0] == "#":
        ''
    else:
        aa_info.append(string.strip())
aa_info
```

Which gave me this output (A list of the .txt file):

```
['Ala\tA\t71.09\tnan',
 'Arg\tR\t156.19\t12.0',
 'Asn\tN\t114.11\tnan',
 'Asp\tD\t115.09\t3.5',
 'Cys\tC\t103.15\t8.6',
 'Gln\tQ\t128.15\tnan',
 'Glu\tE\t129.12\t4.3',
 'Gly\tG\t57.05\tnan',
 'His\tH\t137.14\t6.5',
 'Ile\tI\t113.16\tnan',
 'Leu\tL\t113.16\tnan',
 'Lys\tK\t128.17\t10.4',
 'Met\tM\t131.19\tnan',
 'Phe\tF\t147.18\tnan',
 'Pro\tP\t97.12\tnan',
 'Ser\tS\t87.08\tnan',
 'Thr\tT\t101.11\tnan',
 'Trp\tW\t186.21\tnan',
 'Tyr\tY\t153.18\t10.4',
 'Val\tV\t99.14\tnan']
```

I then generated a dictionary from this list with this command:

```
aa_props = {}
for line in aa_info:
    key = line.split("\t")[0]
    value = line.split("\t")[1:]
    a_dictionary[key] = value
print(a_dictionary)
```

With output:

```
{'Ala': ['A', '71.09', 'nan'], 'Arg': ['R', '156.19', '12.0'], 'Asn': ['N', '114.11', 'nan'], 'Asp': ['D', '115.09', '3.5'], 'Cys': ['C', '103.15', '8.6'], 'Gln': ['Q', '128.15', 'nan'], 'Glu': ['E', '129.12', '4.3'], 'Gly': ['G', '57.05', 'nan'], 'His': ['H', '137.14', '6.5'], 'Ile': ['I', '113.16', 'nan'], 'Leu': ['L', '113.16', 'nan'], 'Lys': ['K', '128.17', '10.4'], 'Met': ['M', '131.19', 'nan'], 'Phe': ['F', '147.18', 'nan'], 'Pro': ['P', '97.12', 'nan'], 'Ser': ['S', '87.08', 'nan'], 'Thr': ['T', '101.11', 'nan'], 'Trp': ['W', '186.21', 'nan'], 'Tyr': ['Y', '153.18', '10.4'], 'Val': ['V', '99.14', 'nan'], '': []}
```

But I need the dictionary to be separated differently.  I need the key to be the one letter amino acid codes and the value to be the 3 letter amino acid code, molecular weight, and charge.
ie. for the first dictionary key and value I need it to be:

```
'A': ['Ala', '71.09', 'nan']
```

When I enter the input to look something this (I have tried a few different variations of numbers) to create a dictionary:

```
aa_props = {}
for line in aa_info:
    key = line.split("\t")[1]
    value = line.split("\t")[2:]
    a_dictionary[key] = value
print(a_dictionary)
```

An error pops up: 'List index out of range'

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using `''` for passing by a line in your first for loop, use the `pass` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line with a dict comprehension:

```py
aa_props = {arr[1]: [arr[0]] + arr[2:] for arr in map(lambda x: x.split("\t"), aa_info)}
```

This concatenates `[arr[0]]` with `arr[2:]` to essentially slice around the first element.

Comment: Make sure `aa_info` doesn't have an empty entry as the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Read in data:

```
infilename = 'aa_data.txt'
infile = open(infilename,'r')
aa = infile.readlines()
```

Clean it up:

```
aa_info = []
for string in aa:
        if string[0] == '#':
            ''
        elif string[0] == '\n':
            ''
        else:
            aa_info.append(string.strip())
```

Add commas as separators:

```
aa_info_list = []
for string in aa_info:
    string = string.split('\t')
    aa_info_list.append(string)
```

Create dictionary:
aa_props = {}

```
for aa in aa_info_list:
    props = [aa[0], float(aa[2]), float(aa[3])]
    aa_props[aa[1]] = props
```